# Converting an LWP::UserAgent from Perl to Ruby

Tags: ruby, httprequest

I am trying to add a `User-Agent` to the header in my HTTP request (in Ruby), but am unsure of the format of the user-agent string. here is how it is defined in Perl:

```
use LWP::UserAgent;
my $ua = new LWP::UserAgent(keep_alive=>1);
$ua->credentials($netloc, '', "$user", "$pwd");
```

If I try to `print $ua;`, I get a hash which changes every time. I believe that in Ruby I should have the credentials embedded into a single string. How can I know how to format this string? Or, How can I successfully print the contents of `$ua` in Perl?

Ruby code:

`http = Net::HTTP.new("your.site.com", 80)
req = Net::HTTP::Get.new("/path/to/the/page.html", {'User-Agent' => '`**your_agent_here**`'})
response = http.request(req)`

Comment: Please edit your question to include the Ruby code you've written so far.

Comment: @Jordan I have added ruby code and bolded the part I'm unsure about

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your Perl example does not show you setting the User-Agent header (using the `agent` method). That's the header that identifies the software performing the transaction. You are adding Basic Auth credentials in the Perl example, which is how the user demonstrates they are allowed to access the resource. They are completely different things.

When you `print $ua`, you are seeing the memory address of the object, like `LWP::UserAgent=HASH(0x7fa9db00b1b0)`.

If you want to set the User-Agent string in the Ruby example, fill in the string you want.

If you want to supply the username and password for Basic Authorization, see the example in the [Net::HTTP docs](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.3.0/libdoc/net/http/rdoc/Net/HTTP.html):

```
uri = URI('http://example.com/index.html?key=value')

req = Net::HTTP::Get.new(uri)
req.basic_auth 'user', 'pass'

res = Net::HTTP.start(uri.hostname, uri.port) {|http|
  http.request(req)
}
puts res.body
```